# Why does only a portion turn white?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a page and here's what is happening. I'm trying to get it all white but only a small portion of it turns white. Also its an `h1` but its coming out as a `p`. Any ideas. [Here](http://jsbin.com/fetizozu/1/edit)'s a demo and the code.

[image]

Comment: You're unclear in what you're asking... Your demo has a div that says HEY under the color changing div. if you dont want to see that just add "overflow:hidden;" in your body CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `position: absolute;` so the div doesn't know how wide to be.  Do this:

```
#content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    /* edit */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* or */
    width: 100%;
    /* end edit */
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Also, I don't know what you mean about coming out as a `p`.  It's an `h1` for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see with your code:

1. Your `#content` div uses absolute positioning. If you want it to be full width, you will either need to define the CSS `display` property to `block` or set the CSS `width` property to `100%`.
2. If you want the entire screen to have a white background, you should set the CSS `background` property of HTML to `white`.
3. When inspecting your code, the text "hey" still shows as `<h1>`. What makes you say that it is `<p>`?